# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Name>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

this is the "The Net Ninja" code adapted to the more recently flutter version by me:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:coffee_for_all/models/coffee.dart';
import 'package:coffee_for_all/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:coffee_for_all/services/database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'coffee_list.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  var initialData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Coffee>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().coffees,
      initialData: initialData,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Coffee for all'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text('logout'),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                primary: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: CoffeeList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And when I try to run the program this happens:
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 5 of 680 libraries in 937ms.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ════════════════
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List'
The relevant error-causing widget was
Home
lib\screens\wrapper.dart:18
══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

And this is where and how I define the List:

```
class Coffee {
  final String? name;
  final String? sugars;
  final int? strength;

  Coffee({this.name, this.sugars, this.strength});
}


class CoffeeList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CoffeeListState createState() => _CoffeeListState();
}

class _CoffeeListState extends State<CoffeeList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final coffees = Provider.of<List<Coffee>>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: coffees.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return CoffeeTile(coffee: coffees[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}


  // coffee list from snapshot
  List<Coffee> _coffeeListFromSnapShop(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Coffee(
        name: doc.get('name') ?? '',
        strength: doc.get('strength') ?? 0,
        sugars: doc.get('sugars') ?? '0',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  // get coffees stream

  Stream<List<Coffee>> get coffees {
    return coffeeCollection.snapshots().map(_coffeeListFromSnapShop);
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks!

Comment: could comment the line giving error!

Comment: Sounds like somewhere you are passing `null` to something that is expecting a `List`.

Comment: lib\screens\wrapper.dart:18 In my other answer I have the wrapper file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. There is no null check with the itemCount attribute of ListView.builder().

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final coffees = Provider.of<List<Coffee>>(context);

  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: coffees!=null?coffees.length:0,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return CoffeeTile(coffee: coffees[index]);
   },
 );
```

}
}

Comment: A shorter solution would be:
itemCount:  coffees?.length ?? 0

Comment: That shorter solution don't work in this version

Answer (score 0):

But that results in:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<Coffee>'
The relevant error-causing widget was
Home
lib\screens\wrapper.dart:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Being my wrapper file this:

```
import 'package:coffee_for_all/screens/authenticate/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:coffee_for_all/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Uid?>(context);

    // return either Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the initialData wasn't defined but now is working with:

```
initialData: [],
```